# MongoDB Aggregation - Keeping field names

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents that are scores per round of golf. I am trying to:

- group these by `playerId`
- total the scores across ALL rounds (documents)
- `$push` the original document's array of `$holes` for later use
- add each original document's `courseId` into the above array, to reference later

I have everything but the last part, with this Aggregation stage:

```
{
  _id: "$playerName",
  total: {
    $sum: "$total"
  },
  rounds: { $push: "$holes" }
}
```

I don't know how to add extra fields to this stage keeping the `courseId` value from each source document. I have seen `$$ROOT` but I don't need everything.

When I do this, `rounds` is an `Array` of `Objects`, as:

```
{
  "_id" : "Tiger Woods",
  "total" : 45
  "rounds" : {
    0 : { { 1 : 2 }, { 2: 2 }, ... },
    1 : { ... },
    2 : { ... }
  }
}
```

[image: round sub-doc structure]

I would like to put in the `key` name part of the above array with the `courseId` value, so it can be used later - or any other way to reference it:

```
{
  "_id" : "Tiger Woods",
  "total" : 45
  "rounds" : {
    "course1" : { ... },
    "course2" : { ... },
    "courseN" : { ... }
  }
}
```

The original document structure is - there is 1 document "per comp per course" played:

```
{
    "compId": "607019361c071256e4f0d0d5",
    "courseId": "608952e3abebbd503ba6e115",
    "playerId": "609d0993906429612483cea0",
    "holes": {
        "1": 2,
        "2": 1,
        "3": 2,
        "4": 2,
        "5": 2,
        "6": 2,
        "7": 0,
        "8": 2,
        "9": 3
    },
    "playerName": "Tiger Woods",
    "total": 16
}
```

I need to reference which `courseId` with each `rounds` array element. I thought it might be the `key` part of the key/value pair but I can only name the whole `Array` as "rounds"

Or maybe it's because the original `holes` is an Object, not an Array? How would I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$group` the `$arrayToObject`

- when you `$group` it, you can make it as key value pair(k,v). By using the `$arrayToObject` u can get the desired outpur

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$playerName",
      total: { $sum: "$total" },
      rounds: {
        $push: {
          k: "$courseId",
          v: "$holes"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      rounds: { "$arrayToObject": "$rounds" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-F8gKjJi0Cu)**

Comment: Thanks @varman, this works as I asked for. I didn't think I would need an extra stage of processing to achieve it though. Also why do I HAVE to use `k` and `v` as the field names in the `$push` method? If I try anything else, the `$addFields` stage errors with "$arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v'. Missing either or both keys from: {courseId: "608955aaabebbd503ba6e116", holes: {6: 1, 9: 2, 4: 2, 7: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 8: 2, 5: 2}}". Is this hardcoded like this?